# For loop increment by values taking from another array

Tags: javascript

```
var z=[1,1,1,1,1,5,1,1,3]

 var data1=[];;

for(var q=0;q<20;q=q+z)
```

I want to increment values not in a regular pattern like `q++`, but the increment is to be done in a pattern like `+1,+1,+1,+1,+1,+5,+1,+1,+3.` Is it possible?

Comment: not sure what you are getting at.  Are you summing the `z` array?

Comment: use nested loop

Comment: something like `for(var q=0;q<20;q=q + z[q])`?

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Answer (score 2):

**What you want**

The following adds successive items in `z` to `q` during each iteration of the loop.

```
var z = [1,1,1,1,1,5,1,1,3];

for (var q = 0, index = 0; q < 20; q = q + z[index++]) {

}
```

**Side note**

You will clearly have an issue before the loop finishes. Your loop runs until `q` is 20, but you will run out of items in your `z` array before `q` reaches 20. You only have 9 items in your `z` array, which means you can access up to the 8th index. Accessing indexes beyond the array length will return `undefined`. Adding `undefined` to `q` will produce `NaN`.

```
q:0, index: 0
q:1, index: 1
q:2, index: 2
q:3, index: 3
q:4, index: 4
q:5, index: 5
q:10, index: 6
q:11, index: 7
q:12, index: 8
q:15, index: 9 (danger)
```

**End Early**

Depending on what you actually want, one way to workaround this is to change your loop ending logic to take into account the length of the `z` array, compared to the `index`. This is unnecessary if your `z` array is actually much longer.

```
var z = [1,1,1,1,1,5,1,1,3];

for (var q = 0, index = 0; q < 20 && index < z.length; q = q + z[index++]) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That should do it - no inner loops. Watch out for i < n from now on.

```
var z=[1,1,1,1,1,5,1,1,3];
for(var i = 0, j = 0; i < 20; i+=z[j++]) {
    console.log(i, j)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?:

```
for(var q=0;q<z.length;q=q + z[q]){
   console.log("z[q] = " + z[q]);
   console.log("q =" + q);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you want to do is possible.  In a [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) statement, the final portion of it says "do this at the end of each iteration", then on the next iteration check to see if the condition is still true.

```
var z=[1,1,1,1,1,5,1,1,3]

 var data1=[];;

for(var q=0;q<20;q=q+z)
```

You problem is here: `q=q+z`.  `z` is an array, and not a number, you need to specify which value in the array you want to add to `q`.  You could so something like this:

`for(var q=0;q<20;q=q+z[q])` or `this for(var q=0;q<20;q=q+z[2])` but you need something to specify which value in the array you want to use.  You could create a separate value to increment so that the indexed value of array z uses the next value on each loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple variables in the first expression of the for loop and then use it to index the `z` array like so:

```js
var z=[1,1,1,1,1,5,1,1,3];

for(var q=0, i=0;q<20;q+=z[i], i++){
  console.log(q);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function irregfor(func){   
   var total=0;
  while(total<20){total=[1,1,1,1,1,5,1,1,3].reduce((index,inc)=>{func(index+=inc);return index;},total)}
}
```

Use like this:

```
irregfor(function(index){
  console.log(index);
});
```

http://jsbin.com/vakutonave/edit?console

Answer (score 0):

You could use an additional variable as index for the array.

With incrementing the index variable, you could use a remainder operator to keep the index smaller than the length of `z`.

```js
var z = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 3],
    data = [];

for (var i = 0, q = 0; q < 30; q += z[i], i = (i + 1) % z.length) {
    console.log(i, z[i], q);
    data.push(q);
}
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you increment only one var in your code...

```
var count=0;
function irregIncre(val){
    var arr = [1,1,1,1,1,5,1,1,3];
    if(count >= arr.length){ count = count % arr.length; }
    return val + arr[count++];
}
var num = 0;
num = irregIncre(num); //many times you wish...
```

To increment more variables, I would use an identifier

```
var countA=[];
function irregIncreM(val, id){
    countA[id] = countA[id] ? countA[id] : 0;
    var arr = [1,1,1,1,1,5,1,1,3];
    if(countA[id] >= arr.length){ countA[id] = countA[id] % arr.length; }
    return val + arr[countA[id]++];
}
var num1 = 0;
var num2 = 0;
num1 = irregIncre(num1, 'num1'); //many times you wish...
num2 = irregIncre(num2, 'num2'); //many other times you wish...
```

[Link to JsBin](http://jsbin.com/kojuzohohe/edit?js,console)

Answer (score -1):

Something like this. Using a counter variable to increment the value of Z.

```js
var z=[1,1,1,1,1,5,1,1,3]

var data1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 35];;

var i = 0;
var zincrement = z[i];

for(var q=0;q<20;q=q+zincrement){
console.log(data1[q]);
i++;
zincrement = z[i];
}
```